# Getting jQuery for loop printing my function by incrementing values

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am dealing with strange issue, but that should be a simple solution as my mind totally stuck I don't know where I am going wrong, simply I want to put my function thrice as shown below in example:

If my function is :

```
function(){
    if (jQuery('#gallery-v').length) {
        var $container = jQuery('#gallery-v');
        alert($container);
        $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
            $container.isotope({
                filter: '*',
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            });
        });
        jQuery('#filterlist_v a').click(function() {
            alert(this);
            jQuery('#filterlist_v .current').removeClass('current');
            jQuery(this).addClass('current');

            var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
            $container.isotope({
                filter: selector,
                animationOptions: {
                    duration: 750,
                    easing: 'linear',
                    queue: false
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }
}
```

I simply want it to be two times more by just incrementing my selector value like `'#gallery-v'` to `'#gallery-v1'` and for `'#filterlist_v a'` to `'#filterlist_v1 a'` just simply increment my `gallery-v` by 1 in first iteration 2 in second and so on etc ...

Here is my code which I tried:

```
var count = 2;
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++){
 function(){
        if (jQuery('#gallery-v' +i +'').length) {
            var $container = jQuery('#gallery-v' +i +'');
            alert($container);
            $container.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: '*',
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false
                    }
                });
            });
            jQuery('#filterlist_v' +i +' a').click(function() {
                alert(this);
                jQuery('#filterlist_v +i +' .current').removeClass('current');
                jQuery(this).addClass('current');

                var selector = jQuery(this).attr('data-filter');
                $container.isotope({
                    filter: selector,
                    animationOptions: {
                        duration: 750,
                        easing: 'linear',
                        queue: false
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

but its not printing my code in my js file as I wanted :(
what's going on wrong please ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html code you should change id's of elements to `#gallery-v0` and `#filterlist_v0` because in the first loop (`i === 0`) you get selectors:

```
'#gallery-v' + i + '' -> #gallery-v0
'#filterlist_v0' + i + '' -> filterlist_v0
```

You have another error here: `'#filterlist_v +i +' .current'`, it should be  `'#filterlist_v' + i + ' .current'`. Assuming that first part of code works, that would be works.

Comment: I could not underswtand your words

Comment: errors will be removed for sure, but you have not gotten my point I think this thing (jQuery('#gallery-v' +i +'').length) should become (jQuery('#gallery-v0').length) in first iteration and (jQuery('#gallery_v1').length) in second iteration and so on etc ... i just want to get those selectors from my html page which are living there

Comment: and why should i change my id's ? any issue for that ? as I am getting i value in the loop with out any issue

Comment: Ok, I thought that you have element with id `#gallery-v` in your code and try to get it with this loop, so what is the problem? Is the first part of code working?

Comment: I have #gallery-v0, #gallery-v1, #gallery-v2 in my html ... but I want to have function which filters those html based on each id ... i mean function for every individual item from html like a function for #gallery-v0, then 1 function for #gallery-v1 and last for #gallery-v2 etc ... hope you get it now

Comment: No, it does not work right ... also if I check my script code in the browser it shows same loop ... while I want those three different functions printed with only difference of #gallery-v0, #gallery-v1 and #gallery-v2 ... that's what I want ???